# OpenSSL support for ed25519, encrypting content?

Tags: encryption, openssl

Using OpenSSL 1.1.1.b-1, I can generate an RSA keypair and use them to encrypt content:

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key 4096
openssl rsa -in private_key -pubout -outform PEM -out public_key.pem
```

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public_key.pem -pubin -in original.txt -out encrypted.enc
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private_key -in encrypted.enc -out original.txt
```

But attempting to encrypt content with ed25519 keys,

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm ED25519 -out private_key
openssl pkey -in private_key -pubout -out public_key
```

```
openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -inkey public_key -pubin -in original.txt -out encrypted.enc
```

Results in the error:

```
pkeyutl: Error initializing context
140302731502080:error:0608B096:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init:operation not supported for this keytype:crypto/evp/pmeth_fn.c:141:
```

Is OpenSSL 1.1.1.b-1 unable to perform the function, or am I using pkeyutl incorrectly?

Comment: What is the broader goal you are striving to achieve, in the furtherance of which you have elected to try using `openssl rsautl` and `openssl pkeyutl`?

Comment: The broader goal is to allow a website visitor to leave a message, which uses the above RSA keys through PHP's openssl_public_encrypt function. This way, the visitor does not need to know anything about cryptography, but the message remains encrypted on the server until the admin retrieves it and decrypts it locally.

Comment: Consider using libsodium and crypto_box_seal instead.

Comment: My understanding of libsodium and crypto_box is that it requires more than a single asymmetric keypair, assuming two users each have a public and private key to encrypt and decrypt messages. Or is it possible to use crypto_box with a single keypair?

Comment: crypto_box_seal generates an ephemeral key pair, does crypto_box with it, and sends the public part alongside the ciphertext so the recipient can decrypt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **`openssl rsautl` is *not* for encrypting messages.**  The documentation is extremely bad and misleading and has been that way for decades and it's not my fault.  In general, the `openssl` command-line utilities are *diagnostic tools and debugging aids* for various bits of software and cryptography protocols, most of which were designed many years ago with excessive complexity.

   Essentially nobody should ever use `openssl rsautl`.  The only `openssl` command-line tool that is even *designed* for encrypting *messages* with RSA is `openssl smime`/`openssl cms`—and [badly at that](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59241) because the protocol designers were bureaucrats high on printer fumes.
2. **Ed25519 is a signature scheme.  It does not do encryption.**  There are public-key encryption schemes—authenticated or anonymous—that use some of the same underlying mathematical ideas as Ed25519, but you can't use Ed25519 itself to encrypt messages any more than you can use RSASSA-PSS to encrypt messages.

Comment: If you say ed25519 is a signature scheme and doesn't do encryption, doesn't that contradict with ed25519 commonly used as an SSH security mechanism? i.e. as an alternative way to login using a password. I understand asymmetrical encryption is something different than authentication, but doesn't that essentially still boil down to encryption? (with the consideration that it's unsuitable to encrypt arbitrarily large data, just a random key which is then used in symmetric encryption)

Comment: OK, thanks. But then, what the hell is a good, simple, efficient encrypting system ?
I initially used openssl, then gpg, but some other people yell at GPG being very bad at encryption as well (mostly because of its complexity).
Everyone seems to say every system is bad :/